# Puppet master and client on one machine

Tags: puppet

I would like to test the puppet client on the same machine as the master resides. I followed this tutorial "http://www.elsotanillo.net/2011/08/installing-puppet-master-and-client-in-the-same-host-the-debian-way/". He was saying that generating SSL at the right moment is the trick involved in keeping master and client communicating successfully in one machine. I killed puppet master process, generated puppet.conf file as he given in that link, installed puppet client, but when I try to generate SSL using the below command. It failed. You could see the log below.

**puppetd --no-daemonize --onetime --verbose --waitforcert 30**

```
I replaced puppetd with puppet agent to make it work in latest version of puppet
```

> Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will
>   continue:
>
> Warning: Connection timed out - connect(2)
>
> Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
>
> Error: /File[/home/lhdadmin/.puppet/var/facts.d]: Failed to generate
>   additional resources using 'eval_generate': Connection timed out -
>   connect(2)
>
> Error: /File[/home/lhdadmin/.puppet/var/facts.d]: Could not evaluate:
>   Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppet/pluginfacts:
>   Connection timed out - connect(2)
>
> Info: Retrieving plugin
>
> Error: /File[/home/lhdadmin/.puppet/var/lib]: Failed to generate
>   additional resources using 'eval_generate': Connection timed out -
>   connect(2)
>
> Error: /File[/home/lhdadmin/.puppet/var/lib]: Could not evaluate:
>   Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppet/plugins:
>   Connection timed out - connect(2)

I tried to install puppetdb thinking that was the missing component could be triggering the above error, but it couldn't find puppetdb module to install. see the errors below

**sudo puppet resource package puppetdb ensure=latest**

> Error: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o
>   DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install puppetdb' returned 100:
>   Reading package lists... Building dependency tree... Reading state
>   information... E: Unable to locate package puppetdb Error:
>   /Package[puppetdb]/ensure: change from purged to latest failed: Could
>   not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o
>   DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install puppetdb' returned 100:
>   Reading package lists... Building dependency tree... Reading state
>   information... E: Unable to locate package puppetdb

package { 'puppetdb':   ensure => 'purged', }

Comment: Do I need puppetdb for this to work??

Answer (score 0):

Aah , I think you have not mentioned your puppet class in init.pp or have defined your node in node.pp .
If you don't want to use puppetdb then please don't include in your puppet/puppet.conf file and if you want to use it then cross check the puppetdb by login in manually by the user mentioned in puppet.conf file.

```
storeconfigs = true 
dbname = puppet-db
dbadapter = mysql
dbuser = puppet-user
dbpassword = puppet
dbserver = localhost
```

Also check for the proper repo in `/etc/apt/sources.list` , `E: Unable to locate package puppetdb` this error generally occurs due to failed internet connectivity, or if it is unable to reach the server.